# voting and commenting - how to store the rating data

Tags: android

If i have an app that s a list of hotels with basic info of them (location, rating, pricing, etc), and i want to allow users of my app to vote for a specific hotel (giving it a "stars" rating and a few line comment - much like a rating in the Android Market), how and where do i store thoe rating so they will be available to other app users? i guess it should be online, but how?

Is it recommendable to allow the app to publish the rating online but do the calculations and add the comments on the next app update?

if i decide the latter, how do i control the database that has the comments stored because every comment requires its own field right? so can i have the unified DB for all the data (my info on the hotels, rating, comments) that is automatically expandable for the extra fields for comments?

i hope you undestand what i am asking here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are going to need an external database. I would use MySql as an interface. External databases are a bit trickier than local sqlite. Try looking at this http://www.slideshare.net/kewang/20100607-how-to-access-the-database-using-the-android good luck!

Comment: So, as i understand: Allow users to add data into external DB fields (stars rating is one field i guess, just calculate the average rating with the former average + newest before rewriting the data in that field). Then add a new field for every new comment. Would it be smart to "download" all comments to the SQLLite DB on the device, or just download the rating and show the comments directly from the external DB?
And offcourse, thaks for the reply...

Comment: yeah no worries. your question is all about design.. comments and such are sort of a forum like structure where you have an item (hotel) and it has associated fields (rating, comments, etc) so one way to do it is have a table with HotelID, rating, comments, etc and add a new row upon a user's submission, or seperate tables for rating / comments. I would download the first 10 comments for the user, and display the first 5 with an option to see more. upon asking for this option, you show them 6-10 then cache 11-15v etc. that way there is no lag for the user. and yes, you could have a saved

Comment: average rating for the hotel, but you will need to know how many ratings that is an average of so your new rating can be scaled properly in your average. I think the trickiest part is getting the read / write queries working with an external db, not the symantecs of storage.